# Can not save in XML File

Tags: uwp

I am trying to create an XML File with Visual Studios to save data for UWP.

```
                        await Task.Run(() => { 
        FileStream fs = new FileStream("C:\\Users\\User\\Studienarbeit", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
        KalenderClass kc = new KalenderClass();
        kc.Termin = TerminTextBlock.Text;
        kc.Datum = DatePicker1.Date;
        kc.Person = PersonTextBlock.Text;

        ls.Add(kc);

        xs.Serialize(fs, ls);

        });
```

But when I start my Program it just shows me Code of App.g.i.cs and breaks my app.

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Hi, did you create a UWP project or a Desktop-Bridge project? In UWP, it is not recommended to get the `FileStream` of a file through a path. For file IO, you can refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-reading-and-writing-files). Try to use `StorageFile` and asynchronous method.

Comment: I created an UWP project. How does it work in UWP?

Comment: Hello, there are complete file reading and writing examples in the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-reading-and-writing-files) I gave. If you are interested in how to combine file reading and writing with XML documents, here is a complete example for reference: [XML DOM sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XmlDocument)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try

```
await Task.Run(()=>
{
    //your code
});
```